# Error searching nodes within a linked list java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I thought this would be very easy but I am having problems searching nodes from a text file.

The data from the text file follows:

1

2

3

4

5

The data is being stored in the String "word". They are numbers to avoid complexity.

Issue is- is that it keeps on returning false when calling the search method.

```
public class Search
    {

        static int count;  // number of elements
        Search ()
    {
        count = 0;
    }


    static void inputdata (Node head, Node node) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("Words.txt"));

        String word;
        String line = null;


        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)
        {
            word = (line);
            node = new Node (word);
            node.next = head;
            head = node; // need to set the new head of the list to the node that was just inserted
            count++;
        }


        reader.close ();

        node = head;
        System.out.println ("Here is the list:");
        System.out.println ();
        do
        {
            System.out.println (node.data);
            node = node.next;
        }
        while (node != null);
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ();
    }




    static boolean Found (String search, Node head, Node node)  // recursive search method
    {
        boolean found;

        Node temp; // sets a termpoary node to the head
        node = head;
        temp = head;

        while (temp != null)
        {
            if (temp.data.equals (search))
                return true;
            temp = temp.next;

        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#");

        //Search list = new Search (); //calls list via constructor
        Node head = null;
        Node node = null;

        inputdata (head, node);



        System.out.println (count + " entries");

        String search, repeat;


        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("Which word do you want to search within the linked list?"); // returns true/false from a method
        search = stdin.readLine ();

        System.out.println (Found (search, head, node));

    }
}
```

other file (class):

```
public class Node
{
    Node next, prev;
    String data;

    public Node (String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am having problems" isn't a description of the problem. What do you need help with, exactly?

Comment: But a quick read of the code easily shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your linked list only ever has one object in it at a time, since you are always setting node.next to head, and head to node. Therefore, you will always only print the same number (which I am going to guess, is exactly what you're seeing).

What you need to do is to fix your insertion routine. Something like this should do (mind you that it's untested)

```
Node prev;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    word = line;
    node = new Node(word);
    node.next = null;

    if(head == null) {
        head = node;
    } 

    if(prev != null) {
        prev.next = node;
    }
    prev = node;

}
```